# Does orientdb have a key-value API?

Tags: orientdb

Orientdb states that one of its models is key-value store. However, I can't find anything in the java API docs that describes objects or methods that facilitate key-value. Instead, I get the impression that by key value they simply mean a class that has an indexed primary key along with a linked document / graph object. And that the key value is just a normal sql lookup on an indexed key.   Am I missing anything?

Adam

Answer (score 0):

The OrientDB engine supports Graph, Document, Key/Value, and Object models, so you can use OrientDB as a replacement for a product in any of these categories. However, the main reason why users choose OrientDB is because of its true Multi-Model.

The Document Model stores the data inside documents. A document is a set of key/value pairs (also referred to as fields or properties), where the key allows access to its value.

The Key Value ModelThis is the simplest model of the three. Everything in the database can be reached by a key, where the values can be simple and complex types. OrientDB supports Documents and Graph Elements as values allowing for a richer model, than what you would normally find in the classic Key/Value model. The classic Key/Value model provides "buckets" to group key/value pairs in different containers.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Document-and-graph-model.html

Hope it helps

Regards